# How to spawn integration tests in a CPU core pool using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

We are using the following tech stack

- NodeJS
- PostgreSQL
- Cypress

We have many integration tests and we are getting to the point where we should parallelize the test cases. When I used to work with Python, we had `multiprocessing` library that allowed us to easily dispatch things to multiple cores in a pool. For example, you would loop through all the things you need to dispatch and if you've exhausted all cores you would wait until the next one is available.

Comment: How about writing a Node.js script to perform your integration tests? Or you could just use Python the way you used to -- dispatching things you need, presumably Node.js processes or what have you.

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization#Overview

Comment: @amn Yes, right now I am running `cypress run` from the command line but I am looking to start the test in my NodeJS script. In there I want to be able to dispatch the tests in multi-core pool way as I described. I will edit the original post to add this detail in the question.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Yes I looked into that but that requires you to run the tests in multiple machines. The way we have dockerized things across multiple repos kind of makes this quite complex. I see doing the multi-core way within one machine a nice performance boost before we get into this complex solution.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_class_worker

Answer (score -1):

Please use this package for  parallel-testing
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-parallel-tests